# Mechanize: redirect to a url after login which is different from the landing page after login

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I'm trying to login to a page of a website using mechanize(python). When I login, the page is redirected to the landing page. But, I wish to open another URL which can only be opened after login. Can anyone please tell me how to do it? I checked out the documentation but couldn't find an answer. Google search didn't help too. Please help.
**main.py**

```
import mechanize,cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from CAPTCHA import CaptchaParser
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO


br = mechanize.Browser()
...

br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(True)
br.set_cookiejar(cookielib.CookieJar())
br.set_handle_redirect(mechanize.HTTPRedirectHandler)
...

login = br.open("https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp")
html = login.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
im = soup.find('img',id='imgCaptcha')
imgresponse = br.open_novisit(im['src'])
image = Image.open(StringIO(imgresponse.read()))
parser = CaptchaParser()
captcha = parser.getCaptcha(image)

br.select_form(name="stud_login")
regno=raw_input("Enter registration number: ")
passwd=raw_input("Enter passowrd: ")

br['regno']=regno
br['passwd']=passwd
br['vrfcd']=captcha

br.submit()
if br.geturl()!='https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/home.asp':
    print "login error"
```

The page which is opened is `https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/home.asp`. From here I wish to redirect to `https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/coursepage_plan_view.asp?sem=FS`.

Comment: You can not. You have to submit form first, then open a new page.

Comment: I've submitted the form, i.e., I've successfully logged in. From the landing page I need to redirect to another url.

Comment: Have you tried something yet ? Show your code please

Comment: yup..I included the code.

Comment: so, then juste use `open`: `br.open("http://www.example.com/")`

Comment: Tried that.. It didn't work.. When I use br.geturl() after `br.open('https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/coursepage_plan_view.asp?sem=FS')`, it still returns `https://vtop.vit.ac.in/student/home.asp`.